# Google Maps native directions iphone MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-maps, mkmapview

Can I to open a MKMapView with directions from multiple places. I do not want to call the google maps api where it will open is a separate window. I want to place info on the stops if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

My suggested starting sequence for achieving this is:

1. Read up on MKOverlay, MKOverlayPathView and related MapKit classes.
2. Fetch the directions in a background thread from a provider (eg Google API). This doesn't open in a separate window, you can do it all in background with some API calls. Parse the results into a local model for your stops.
3. Show your map view, and generate overlays from your directions model data.

You'll add Annotations for your stops, and they will have "callouts" so that the users can view some details about them. I believe there are plenty of examples readily available that demonstrate how to do this.

I hope this very general answer is of some use, perhaps just to let you know that what you want to do is readily achievable, and doesn't require much code.

Answer (score 0):

you can request directions from one of the APIs available (Google,...), parse them and draw them as overlay on your MapView, but I recently stumbled over a commercial framework which saved me a lot of time and hassle:
http://mtdirectionsk.it